# Redirection of STDERR to STDOUT and then to a file

Tags: shell, scripting, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I'm using the following code to write in to a file called `maintainence.log`

```
`LOCALHOST:>less wrap.sh | grep avsp
```

`avsp=$`(`df -kh | grep "/global/backups" | awk -F " " '{ print $4 }'` `2>&1`
`echo "Info $DATE: Available diskspace $avsp" >> maintainence.log`
but when i run the script wrap.sh `LOCALHOST:>./wrap.sh` I'm getting the below output:

```
df: `/lfs/wwwmnt/lt2-p-web-intra1': Stale NFS file handle
df: `/lfs/wwwmnt/lt2-p-web-intra1': Stale NFS file handle
```

However, my intention is to have both Errors and STDout written to the file `maintainence.log`.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically saying:

```
var=$(command) >> maintainence.log 2>&1
```

So that the redirection does not affect the execution of `command`. Instead, put the redirection within the `$()` to redirect stderr to stdout and `echo` it later on:

```
var=$(command 2>&1)
echo "$var" >> maintenance.log
```

In your case:

```
avsp=$(df -kh | grep "/global/backups" | awk -F " " '{ print $4 }' 2>&1)
echo "Info $DATE: Available diskspace $avsp" >> maintainence.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the info . I've made the suggested changes : avsp=$(`df -kh | grep "/global/backups" | awk -F " " '{ print $4 }'` 2>&1)
echo "Info $DATE: Available diskspace $avsp" >> maintainence.log
But still the O/p is same , It's not writing in to the maintainece.log O/p-df: `/lfs/wwwmnt/lt2-p-web-intra1': Stale NFS file handle

Comment: @VinayThupili I have the feeling that you are using some backticks too many. Please edit your original question and paste what are the exact commands you are using.

Comment: @VinayThupili as I just say: edit your question showing the *exact* commands you are using. I cannot understand code in comments.

Comment: @VinayThupili I am losing patience here. I said three times that I cannot understand the code you post in comments, so edit your original question and put them there. Otherwise I am not going to check this any more.

Comment: i've edited the question Please look and let me know , Sorry for the trouble i'm new to the StackOverflow and Couldn't edit the question in a desired way . Or let me know your mail Id so i can mail you .

Comment: @VinayThupili there was an error on my answer, where I added an extra backtick. Now it is fixed. Your solution should be just a copy paste of mine, that is, do not use any backtick, just the syntax `avsp=$(df -kh | grep "/global/backups" | awk -F " " '{ print $4 }' 2>&1)`.